# How to justify this causally consistent execution in the $(vis, ar)$ framework for distributed consistency models?

Tags: pl.programming-languages, dc.distributed-comp, concurrency, formal-methods, consistency-models

In Figure 5.1 of the book ["Principles of Eventual Consistency" by Sebastin Burckhardt, 2014](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/publication/principles-of-eventual-consistency/), [Causal Consistency (CC); wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Causal_consistency) is (mainly) defined as the conjunction of $hb \subseteq vis$ and $hb \subseteq ar$, where $hb \triangleq (so \cup vis)^{+}$.

An execution satisfies CC if it can be extended by adding $vis$ and $ar$ to an abstract execution which justifies the conditions above; see Definition 3.5.

See also the [POPL'2014 paper](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/replDataTypesPOPL13-complete.pdf) and the [CSUR'2016 paper](https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=2926965).

---

Now, consider the execution in the figure below, where $w(x)0$ denotes a write of 0 to $x$ and $r(x)0$ a read of 0 from $x$.

[image: pram-causal-ar]

On the one hand, this execution satisfies CC according to the definition in wiki, because $r(x)1$ can be justified by the serial view of $w(x)0\; w(x)1\; r(x)1$ and $r(x)0$ by $w(x)1\; w(x)0\; r(x)0$.

On the other hand, however, (in my opinion,) it does *not* satisfy CC according to the $(vis, ar)$ definition for CC above. It is impossible to define the total order $ar$ which must put $w(x)0$ before $w(x)1$ (for justifying $r(x)1$) *and* put $w(x)1$ before $w(x)0$ (for justifying $r(x)0$).

---

***My questions:***

1. What is wrong with my argument?
2. How to justify this causally consistent execution in the $(vis, ar)$ framework?